# I'm trying to order variables by key of json inside json

Tags: javascript, json

I'm not really sure how to sum up what I'm trying to do in a single question.  Hopefully I can explain it so it makes sense.

I have a JSON array that lays out a bunch of html slider elements.  They are organized into 3 control panes (Basic, Interface, and Advanced), and each pane has several sliders and switches.  Among other variables, each has a "position" number, and a "label".

```
$json ='[{ "panename": "Basic","pane": "[{\"type\":\"slider\",\"label\":\"Sit Time\",\"id\":\"sitTime\",\"position\":\"0\",\"active\":\"true\"},{\"type\":\"slider\",\"label\":\"Snooze Number\",\"id\":\"snoozeNumber\",\"position\":\"3\",\"active\":\"true\"},{\"type\":\"slider\",\"label\":\"Snooze Duration\",\"id\":\"snoozeDuration\",\"position\":\"4\",\"active\":\"true\"},{\"type\":\"slider\",\"label\":\"Threshold\",\"id\":\"threshold\",\"position\":\"7\",\"active\":\"true\"}]"      },      {        "panename": "Interface",        "pane": "[{\"type\":\"slider\",\"label\":\"Volume\",\"position\":\"5\",\"active\":\"true\"},{\"type\":\"slider\",\"label\":\"LED\",\"id\":\"ledBrightness\",\"position\":\"9\",\"active\":\"true\"},{\"type\":\"switch\",\"label\":\"Notifications\",\"id\":\"notifications\",\"position\":\"12\",\"active\":\"true\"},{\"type\":\"switch\",\"label\":\"Notification Sound\",\"id\":\"notificationSound\",\"position\":\"13\",\"active\":\"true\"},{\"type\":\"switch\",\"label\":\"App Alarms\",\"id\":\"appAlarms\",\"position\":\"14\",\"active\":\"true\"}]"      },      {        "panename": "Advanced",        "pane": "[{\"type\":\"slider\",\"label\":\"Flextime\",\"id\":\"flextime\",\"position\":\"11\",\"active\":\"true\"},{\"type\":\"switch\",\"label\":\"Natural Mode\",\"id\":\"naturalMode\",\"position\":\"2\",\"active\":\"true\"},{\"type\":\"switch\",\"label\":\"SCM\",\"id\":\"scm\",\"position\":\"10\",\"active\":\"true\"},{\"type\":\"switch\",\"label\":\"Confirm Save\",\"id\":\"confirmSave\",\"position\":\"8\",\"active\":\"true\"},{\"type\":\"switch\",\"label\":\"Lockout\",\"id\":\"lockout\",\"position\":\"6\",\"active\":\"true\"}]"}]';
```

What I'm trying to do is parse the entire thing to end up with a string of labels in order by position.  Keep in mind, there are 14 sliders/switches total, so for example, sliders 0 and 1 (sitTime, releaseTime) are on the "Basic" pane and switch 2 (naturalMode) is on the "Advanced" pane. I want do something like this:

```
var labelStr='';
for (x=0;x < number of objects; x++){
    if ('position' == x){
      labelStr= labelStr + ',' +  label of object at position x;
    }

//For example:
// if ('position' == 0){
//    labelStr= labelStr +',' + 'sitTime';
//   }

}
```

Ultimately, I would get a string like:

```
labelStr= "sitTime, releaseTime, naturalMode, snoozeNumber, snoozeDuration, volume, lockout ..."
```

I just have no idea how to parse my JSON in order to get what I want.

Comment: I tried parsing the JSON and it doesn't seem to parse. If you can fix it, I can lend a hand with the rest.

Comment: Why is your `pane` property a string `"pane": "[{\"type\":\"slider\",\"label\":\"Sit Time\",\"id\":\"sitTime\",\"position\":\"0\",\"active\":\"true\"},{\"type\":\"slider\",\"label\":\"Snooze Number\",\"id\":\"snoozeNumber\",\"position\":\"3\",\"active\":\"true\"},{\"type\":\"slider\",\"label\":\"Snooze Duration\",\"id\":\"snoozeDuration\",\"position\":\"4\",\"active\":\"true\"},{\"type\":\"slider\",\"label\":\"Threshold\",\"id\":\"threshold\",\"position\":\"7\",\"active\":\"true\"}]"    
` instead of an object?

Comment: It's probably an array of JSON strings, so it's kind of double-encoded. A bit goofy, but not uncommon, especially if it's stored as JSON in a database or something.

Comment: Is it bc of the line breaks?  It validated when I tried it.  I removed the breaks.  Does that help?

Comment: You would have to replace each and every `\\` with `\\\` to `JSON.parse($json)`

Answer (score 0):

```js
let json ='[{ "panename": "Basic","pane": "[{\\"type\\":\\"slider\\",\\"label\\":\\"Sit Time\\",\\"id\\":\\"sitTime\\",\\"position\\":\\"0\\",\\"active\\":\\"true\\"},{\\"type\\":\\"slider\\",\\"label\\":\\"Snooze Number\\",\\"id\\":\\"snoozeNumber\\",\\"position\\":\\"3\\",\\"active\\":\\"true\\"},{\\"type\\":\\"slider\\",\\"label\\":\\"Snooze Duration\\",\\"id\\":\\"snoozeDuration\\",\\"position\\":\\"4\\",\\"active\\":\\"true\\"},{\\"type\\":\\"slider\\",\\"label\\":\\"Threshold\\",\\"id\\":\\"threshold\\",\\"position\\":\\"7\\",\\"active\\":\\"true\\"}]"      },      {        "panename": "Interface",        "pane": "[{\\"type\\":\\"slider\\",\\"label\\":\\"Volume\\",\\"position\\":\\"5\\",\\"active\\":\\"true\\"},{\\"type\\":\\"slider\\",\\"label\\":\\"LED\\",\\"id\\":\\"ledBrightness\\",\\"position\\":\\"9\\",\\"active\\":\\"true\\"},{\\"type\\":\\"switch\\",\\"label\\":\\"Notifications\\",\\"id\\":\\"notifications\\",\\"position\\":\\"12\\",\\"active\\":\\"true\\"},{\\"type\\":\\"switch\\",\\"label\\":\\"Notification Sound\\",\\"id\\":\\"notificationSound\\",\\"position\\":\\"13\\",\\"active\\":\\"true\\"},{\\"type\\":\\"switch\\",\\"label\\":\\"App Alarms\\",\\"id\\":\\"appAlarms\\",\\"position\\":\\"14\\",\\"active\\":\\"true\\"}]"      },      {        "panename": "Advanced",        "pane": "[{\\"type\\":\\"slider\\",\\"label\\":\\"Flextime\\",\\"id\\":\\"flextime\\",\\"position\\":\\"11\\",\\"active\\":\\"true\\"},{\\"type\\":\\"switch\\",\\"label\\":\\"Natural Mode\\",\\"id\\":\\"naturalMode\\",\\"position\\":\\"2\\",\\"active\\":\\"true\\"},{\\"type\\":\\"switch\\",\\"label\\":\\"SCM\\",\\"id\\":\\"scm\\",\\"position\\":\\"10\\",\\"active\\":\\"true\\"},{\\"type\\":\\"switch\\",\\"label\\":\\"Confirm Save\\",\\"id\\":\\"confirmSave\\",\\"position\\":\\"8\\",\\"active\\":\\"true\\"},{\\"type\\":\\"switch\\",\\"label\\":\\"Lockout\\",\\"id\\":\\"lockout\\",\\"position\\":\\"6\\",\\"active\\":\\"true\\"}]"}]';
json=JSON.parse(json);
let arr=json.map((x)=>(JSON.parse(x.pane)));
arr=[].concat(...arr);
arr.sort((x,y)=>Number(x.position)-Number(y.position));
console.log(arr);
```